# Maven Build is not reading files in webinf/lib folder

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a jar in the Web-INF/lib folder.

When I do a Maven build in Eclipse, it fails because Maven is not reading that jar file.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MerchantWallet</groupId>
  <artifactId>StellarReceive</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>StellarReceive Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- hello -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>StellarReceive</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Here is my folder structure:[image]

Can someone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven expects to be in charge of populating the WEB-INF/lib directory with jars.

You need to remove that jar from it's current location and either install it into your local repository using [mvn install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html), or, if you're using a repository manager (which is preferable), deploy it to that by using either it's UI or by using [mvn deploy:deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html).